# How to prevent multiple instances of my application

Tags: vb.net

I discovered a bug in visual basic. In practice, after completing my application, clicking on the executable file that starts normally, but if I click again on the executable file (exe), inexplicably opens a second window, getting two processes started unnecessarily. I was wondering if there was a way, maybe in some settings, to start the application once and only if you have already started and the user clicks on it again, the controls and not the start. You can do this?

Comment: Yes, sure this seems a vb bug that none noticed before.

Comment: How is this a bug in VB?

Comment: I usually add a function that exits the application if the same appliction is already running.

Comment: `Project -> Properties -> Application -> Make Single Instance App` this is not a bug, sometimes you *want* more than one instance (ex: I have 3 instances of VS running)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just go to the Project properties and set the appropriate checkbox

[image]